# Релиз не грузиться

Tags: github

Я пытаюсь загрузить релиз на гитхаб но пишет такую ошибку

> We weren’t able to create the release for you. Make sure you have a valid tag.

Comment: надо создать тэг......так вот и пишет напрямую.....

Comment: Лол, я подумала что название кривое, спс